# Accessing assets in an Electron/Svelte project?

Tags: electron, svelte, electron-builder, svelte-3

I've used `Electron` and `Electron-Builder` for a long time and am now learning `Svelte` and trying to use it in my projects. I've got the simple 'hello world' project up and running  using this [tutorial](https://dev.to/khangnd/build-a-desktop-app-with-electron-and-svelte-44dp) but I am confused about how to reference packaged assets– for example images or json files in an included 'assets' folder. An image of my directory structure is below.

If I `console.log( __dirname);` in my Svelte component I get `/Users/UserName/electron_workspace/electron-app-svelte/public` – which I understand is the compiled component context - but my 'assets' folder is in the 'src' directory.

Do I put my 'assets' folder in the 'public' directory rather than 'src'? (And I guess 'git-ignore' the 'build' folder?)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the simple (and obvious, I guess) answer is to store project assets in the 'public' directory of the project, per this 2021 article: [Directory and files structure of Svelte projects](https://akashmittal.com/file-structure-svelte-project/)

> **public folder**
> This folder holds the production ready files. So, if
> your project has images, videos, other multimedia, svg etc. then they
> all will be stored in this folder. When you run npm run build, Svelte
> will compile your files, optimize them and store in build folder
> within public folder. This build folder can be deployed to server.

I've always stored production assets in the project 'src' directory since that is what gets versioned/stored in git compared to the compiled 'dist' (build) directory which does not. I guess I will need to 'git-ignore' the 'build' directory.